# SSRS report ended with an error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I used this expression **=Avg(Fields!AncinitetAntalDag.Value)** to get Average of seniority per employees , But i get #Error and i dont exactly why ! and i'm struggled for hours to find out how can i solved this ! Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**Design :** 
[image: ds]

**Preview :** 
[image]

**Query Design :** 
 
[image]

**Query:**

```
SELECT
(CASE
WHEN u.ResignationDate IS NOT NULL THEN
CONVERT(varchar(11), DATEDIFF(day, WorkStartDate, ResignationDate)) 
ELSE
CONVERT(varchar(11), DATEDIFF(day, WorkStartDate, GETDATE())) 
end) as SeniorityViaNumberDay
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've converted the value from DATEDIFF to a varchar. You can't average this. Try not converting it and just using the number of days returned from your DATEDIFF.

Her's the query simplified too..

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, WorkStartDate, ISNULL(ResignationDate, GetDate())) AS SeniorityViaNumberDay
```

Comment: tnx Alan , its works. can i ask you just one more question sir ?1

Comment: @ManDown sure, ask away.

Comment: tnx :) my question is ,when you look at Preview in my question i was asked.under Departments ,  i have 2 rows with same name "Bornholm",where one of them contains 1 person  and the another one contains 6 person , BUT that's not what i want . I just wanna One "Bornholm" ,where contains 7 person . i tested many thing but its not works

Comment: Can you post the full query and maybe a data sample. Assuming you are grouping by department, this must mean you have two Bornholms, one may have spaces before or after or some other non-printable characters. Looking at your query design data, one entry does not have "..." at the end which would suggest the other 6 have something we can't see in that column.

Comment: i didn't pay attention , yes you right they have some thing like this in end "...." , is there any SQL commands to remove this or should i do it manually !

Comment: It's probably best to clean the data otherwise you will have to repeat this process for every query of this type. If your department is only ever a single word then you could use select left(Department, charindex(' ', Department)-1) and this will return anything before the first space found. Be careful if you are updating your database using this, make sure there are no leading spaces. If there are you will need to modify the code to be select left(LTRIM(Department), charindex(' ', LTRIM(Department))-1)

Comment: alright i will try and i dont know how to thank you ,but anyway , thank you so much Sir & have great day :)

Comment: Something like UPDATE MyTable SET Department = LEFT(LTRIM(Department), charindex(' ', LTRIM(Department))-1)  This will update the table. Or you can just use the LEFT(LTRIM(Department), charindex(' ', LTRIM(Department))-1) in your query in place of the current Department column. As I said, just be careful if you have departments with more than one word this will truncate the name at the first space. Good luck